# Passing Connection string to the JetEntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, ms-access, entity-framework-6, jet-ef-provider

Using the System.Data.SqlClient provider it is possible to pass a connection string to the DbContext constructor as follows;

```
    public DataContext() //DbContext
    {
        string ConnString = "Connection String Here";
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnString;   

        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
    }
```

Is there a similar way of passing the connection string to the DbContext for the JetEntityFrameworkProvider without using the app.config settings?

Comment: Quoting the author: For question on how to use it, please use stackoverflow, tags _access-ef-provider_ and _jet-ef-provider._

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the statement `Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnString;` creates a Database.Connection using the `App.Config` (so probably SQL Server in your case) without open it. Then you set ConnectionString of just created connection that is a SQL Server connection. You can change the `App.Config` and create always a `JetConnection` or, if you need to connect to different database types, you can use a different overload of DbContext

```
public Context(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, true)
{ }
```

To use this overload the connection to Microsoft Access Database must be a JetConnection.